# SVM class weights combined with scaling in e1071 package

Tags: r

I am working with SVMs from the package e1071 in R and when I deactivate the scaling of the training data (default: `scale = TRUE`) and set the option `class.weights` at the same time I get warnings like the following:

> WARNING: class label 53735512 specified in weight is not found
>
> WARNING: class label 0 specified in weight is not found

Can anyone explain that? An example code is given below, adapted from the documentation.

```
# weights: (example not particularly sensible)
i2 <- iris
levels(i2$Species)[3] <- "versicolor"
summary(i2$Species)
wts <- 100 / table(i2$Species)
wts
m <- svm(Species ~ ., scale=FALSE, data = i2, class.weights = wts)
```

Comment: Same problem here. My class labels are numbers (1,2,3,4 and 6). Tried to set the weights like <<class.weights=c('1'=2, '2'=1.3, '3'=1, '4'=32, '6'=38)>> but doesn't work either. Btw: I didn't change the scaling parameter. Why would you do that at all? Scaling is very important for the performance of the SVM.

Comment: When I try your code, it works for me. No warnings

Comment: Hi. Im having the same problem since using e1071 version 1.6-6. Before I used 1.6-4 and it worked [and when I switch back to 1.6-4 it works fine] Maybe you can try to download the older version.